# Slow flash on certain web pages

Tags: flash, performance

When trying to use [www.songsterr.com](http://www.songsterr.com) for listening guitar tablatures i get a few second lag between diplay and audio. Also, while playing on [chesscube.com](http://www.chesscube.com), moving the pieces is quite horrible because they are draging and responding really slowly - imagine playing blitz chess like that. I have two laptops, one is using Linux mint other Ubuntu. Both computers have the same problem. No problem when using Windows with VM. What can i do to make flash work properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much. Even now, Flash for Linux is a lot less efficient, and it used to be much worse.

Comment: It's sad that this answer is true. Flash is a pretty closed black box. It has never been reliable and it never will - thankfully it's dying a death.

Comment: what about flash alternatives??

Comment: You could try gnash, but it probably won't work with most games.